# Specifying a directory as an input for -injars and -libraryjars for Proguard

Tags: proguard

I was wondering if it is possible to specify a directory as an input for -injars and -libraryjars in ProGuard instead of listing jars individually.

Lets say I have all of mine jars I want to obfuscate in dirA and all the other jars in dirB
I want to be be able to say

-injars dirA
-libraryjars dirB

Is it possible to do? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. See the ProGuard manual > Usage > [Class paths](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#classpath).